# convert string to uint in go lang

Tags: go, go-imagick

I am trying to convert the string to uint on 32-bit ubuntu using the following code. But it always convert it in uint64 despite explicitly passing 32 as the argument in the function. Below in the code mw is the object of the [image magick](https://github.com/gographics/imagick) library. Which returns `uint` when `mw.getImageWidth()` and `mw.getImageHeight()` is called. Also, it accepts the `uint` type argument in the [resize](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/blob/master/imagick/magick_wand_image.go) function.

```
    width :=  strings.Split(imgResize, "x")[0]
    height := strings.Split(imgResize, "x")[1]

    var masterWidth uint = mw.GetImageWidth() 
    var masterHeight uint = mw.GetImageHeight() 

    mw := imagick.NewMagickWand()
    defer mw.Destroy()

    err = mw.ReadImageBlob(img)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        } 

    var masterWidth uint = mw.GetImageWidth() 
    var masterHeight uint = mw.GetImageHeight()

    wd, _ := strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 32)
    ht, _ := strconv.ParseUint(height, 10, 32)

   if masterWidth < wd || masterHeight < ht { 
     err = mw.ResizeImage(wd, ht, imagick.FILTER_BOX, 1)
     if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } 
   }
```

Error is :

```
# command-line-arguments
test.go:94: invalid operation: masterWidth < wd (mismatched types uint and uint64)
goImageCode/test.go:94: invalid operation: masterHeight < ht (mismatched types uint and uint64)
goImageCode/test.go:100: cannot use wd (type uint64) as type uint in argument to mw.ResizeImage
goImageCode/AmazonAWS.go:100: cannot use ht (type uint64) as type uint in argument to mw.ResizeImage
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> [Package strconv](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/)
>
> [func ParseUint](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint)
>
> ```
> func ParseUint(s string, base int, bitSize int) (n uint64, err error)
> ```
>
> ParseUint is like ParseInt but for unsigned numbers.
>
> [func ParseInt](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseInt)
>
> ```
> func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error)
> ```
>
> ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (2 to 36) and returns
>   the corresponding value i. If base == 0, the base is implied by the
>   string's prefix: base 16 for "0x", base 8 for "0", and base 10
>   otherwise.
>
> The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must
>   fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8,
>   int16, int32, and int64.
>
> The errors that ParseInt returns have concrete type *NumError and
>   include err.Num = s. If s is empty or contains invalid digits, err.Err
>   = ErrSyntax and the returned value is 0; if the value corresponding to s cannot be represented by a signed integer of the given size, err.Err
>   = ErrRange and the returned value is the maximum magnitude integer of the appropriate bitSize and sign.

The `bitSize` argument specifies the integer type that the result must
fit into. The `uint` type size is implementation defined, either 32 or 64 bits. The `ParseUint` return type is always `uint64`. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    width := "42"
    u64, err := strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 32)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    wd := uint(u64)
    fmt.Println(wd)
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

Comment: what is the difference between uint, and uint32 or uint and uint64?

Comment: `uint32` is 32 bits, `uint64` is 64 bits, `uint` is implementation defined, either 32 or 64 bits. See [The Go Programming Language Specification: Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types).

Comment: variable need to be u32, err ... not u64 =)

Comment: @bsbak I don't think so, https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#ParseUint returns (uint64, error).

Comment: Why converting in u32 (strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 32)) then in uint... You loose all value above max uint32 ... convert in strconv.ParseUint(width, 10, 64)
see : https://go.dev/play/p/E-_yC56NYkD

Answer (score 2):

Here is short way to convert string to uint.

```
import (
    "strconv"
)

...

func StringToUint(s string) uint {
    i, _ := strconv.Atoi(s)
    return uint(i)
}
```

Comment: If you chose to have a uint type, it was because you wanted a positive number that could potentially be twice as large as an INT. By doing this conversion, you halve the max size of a uint https://go.dev/play/p/ukjSoHA1F69